# How do I import a Python package everywhere in my system?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am working on a Python package, which has the following structure

```
m2too
├── bin
├── m2too
│   ├── m2too.egg-info
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── requires.txt
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── aero.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── appo.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── dataprep.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── fitter.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── stat.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── aero.py
│   ├── appo.py
│   ├── dataprep.py
│   ├── fitter.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── run.py
│   └── stat.py
├── CHANGES.txt
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

The package name is `m2too`. From the project base folder, `m2too`, I can `pip install -e .`, which works fine, and from within that directory I can run all the scripts, `import m2too` from within any Python interpreter, etc.

However, whenever I `cd` to anywhere else in the system (including `m2too/m2too`), any `import m2too` statement results in the following:

```
>>> import m2too
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'm2too'
```

I can not figure out why this is.

**EDIT**
My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

My `setup.cfg` looks like this:

```
[metadata]
name = m2too
version = 0.1.0
author = Some Name
author_email = somename@somewhe.re
description = A package to do stuff

[options]
package_dir =
    = m2too
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires = 
    numpy
    matplotlib
    pandas
    scipy

[options.packages.find]
where = m2too
```

Comment: well for starter you should use shell in the project base folder and not from inside, other wise you will get the error

Comment: The project base folder is ```m2too/```, which is where I run the ```pip install -e .``` command.

Comment: It seems like You didn't add your module to path? What `sys.path` shows?

Comment: @AmosMitosLaeballo what i mean is, to work on project from konsole, work form the top base directory and then import thing  according to there, otherwise you need to use  `sys` module to import thing

Comment: @amosmitoslaeballo Show your `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` files. -- Also note that a library needs to be installed for each Python interpreter and/or virtual environment separately. If a library is installed for a single Python interpreter, then it is importable only for that Python interpreter and/or virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Python packaging documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/).

Usually problems like these are solved by having a virtual environment (venv) that has a specific Python interpreter setup and which you can activate anywhere in your system.

Comment: I followed the information provided on [this website](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html). My directory structure is the same as that suggested there.